Flutter: set up Dev Prod Test Environment with envied Package
package url: https://pub.dev/packages/envied
I have set up my variable like API Key and base url in .env file to secure. It works perfectly fine.
I want to differentiate between DEV,TEST,PROD environment, I am not sure should I make 3 different .env file or how can I set up based of 3 different flavours.
Thank you,
import 'package:envied/envied.dart';

part 'env.g.dart';

@envied
abstract class Env {
    @EnviedField(varName: 'KEY')
    static const key = _Env.key;
}

